# Multiple Quorum Disk Witnesses in Windows Failover Clustering?

Tags: windows-server-2019, failovercluster

I believe that I have a need to have 2 separate disk witnesses, but am having trouble finding anything that gives any advice or shows any examples.  If anyone can provide some constructive advice, I would greatly appreciate it.

In a clustered Windows 2019 Hyper-V environment, we are migrating our VMs from an older iSCSI SAN device to a newer one.  We currently have both iSCSI devices mapped and available as clustered storage (e.g. C:\ClusteredStorage\Old and C:\ClusteredStorage\New).

We are going to repurpose the old SAN device for local backup storage, so we do not want to remove it completely.  Because of this, I would think that I should have a need to have 2 separate Disk Witnesses - one for each iSCSI device.  However, I cannot seem to find a way to assign a second Disk Witness role to the intended storage.  Please note that the same clustered servers will need access to both iSCSI devices.

1. Should these disks all be part of the same overall cluster, or should I create a second cluster using the same servers?
2. Or is it just OK to have a single quorum witness to handle the quorums for both iSCSI devices?

Answer (score 1):

You will and should not have multiple witnesses. The idea of witnesses is to break a tie between cluster servers. If you have two servers and they cant talk to each other, neither will be online as none have a majority.
With a witness we can make sure that one server can has a majority.
If you have two witnesses, one per site and the link dies both sites die as neither has more than 50% of the votes.